# GNU Make: support some targets not parallel without add depends

Tags: makefile

the Makefile is something like this.

```
all: host kernel app;

host: host/kconfig;
kernel: kernel/compile kernel/install;
app: app/busybox app/switch app/wifi;

app/busybox: app/busybox/compile app/busybox/install;
app/switch: app/switch/compile app/switch/install;
app/wifi: app/wifi/compile app/wifi/install;

app/busybox/compile:
    make -C busybox
```

the `host` target build host tools. the `kernel` target build kernel. the `app` target build userspace application and kernel modules.

I want to support parallel build. but the parallel strategy and reasons are:

1. host/kernel/app can't be parallel

   build `kernel` only after `host` is built, build `app` only after `kernel` is built.
   but I don't want `kernel` depends on `host`, `app` depends on `kernel`.
   because when I build `app` solely I don't want the `kernel` is built.
2. some app can't be parallel

   switch and wifi are kernel modules, so app/switch/compile and app/wifi/compile can't be parallel.

Now I add `.NOTPARALLEL` to Makefile, so only sub Makefile in rule are parallel, but some targets can actually be parallel, e.g. app/busybox app/boa.

How can I write Makefile to support this flexible parallel build.

Comment: @MadScientist hi

Comment: This feature proposed to GNU Make developer is not adopted which can solve my problem, http://gnu-make.2324884.n4.nabble.com/About-NOTPARALLEL-td11898.html

Comment: The methods for avoiding parallelism are all well-known; there's nothing magical available.  You have to either (a) use make's prerequisite facilities (consider whether order-only prerequisites might help address some concerns), or (b) use a non-parallel sub-make, or (c) disable parallelism in the top-level makefile and use parallel sub-makes.  You don't say why you don't want `kernel` to depend on `host`, exactly: if it's just that you don't want `kernel` to rebuild when `host` changes then that can be accomplished in various ways.

Comment: the main problem depends on kernel is that even kernel is not changed, rebuilt it take long time, so when I build a small app solely that will take too long time. so don't depends on kernel, but build kernel manually when kernel changed. @MadScientist

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment what you are really wanting is for the `app` target to be rebuilt when the `kernel` target rebuilds, but you don't want to rebuild the `kernel` target automatically whenever you ask to rebuild the `app` target.

I'm not sure what this has to do with parallel builds though...??

To do this, just don't have the `app` target depend on the `kernel` target at all.  If you want to have `app` rebuild when you do update `kernel`, then have `app` depend on some file that gets updated when you rebuild `kernel`, but don't have a make target describing how to build that file... make will consider it to be like any other source file.

Something like this:

```
app: .build_target
        ...build app...

kernel:
        ....build kernel...
        touch .build_target
```

Or, if the `kernel` target builds some other file you can have `app` depend on that and you don't need the `touch`.  Now when you build `app` it will only get rebuilt if `.build_target` is newer, but it won't try to build `kernel` (because make doesn't know how to build `.build_target`) unless you specifically say `make kernel`.

**ETA**

If you want `make kernel app` to build both, you can do it like this:

```
app: $(filter kernel,$(MAKECMDGOALS))
```

This way if `kernel` appears as a command-line goal then `app` will depend on it, and if it doesn't it won't.

Comment: kernel and app are independent, build one don't build the other though app depends on kernel, but if build `make kernel app -j8`, kernel should build before app. `.NOTPARALLEL`  meets the requirements, but It also disable parallel in app build.